# Mi Bot de discord repite un mensaje una y otra vez

Tags: javascript

Necesito ayuda porque mi propio Bot de discord repite una y otra vez el mismo mensaje incluso cuando no hago el comando que seleccione, repite el mensaje hasta que cierre el cmd y lo vuelva a iniciar el código que estoy usando es

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const  client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
   console.log("CH0");
});
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.content.startsWith("hola")) {
    message.channel.send("Hola que tal!");
  }else
    if (message.content.startsWith("r!estoy solito")) {
  }  message.channel.send("mira atras tuyo :)");
});
```

La verdad no se por que pasa esto Ayuda por favor :(

Comment: Esto: `message.channel.send("mira atras tuyo :)");` quedó fuera del bloque `if` anidado, por lo cual, si no se cumple la primera condición: `if (message.content.startsWith("hola"))` siempre se ejecutarà el bloque `else`, y al tener el mensaje fuera del bloque anidado, se ejecutará siempre el mismo. Revisa la lógica, ya que está mal o simplemente dejaste el comando fuera del `if` anidado. Parece un error de tipeo. Saludos

Comment: Revisa tu anidación, por que está mal anidado para empezar**

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionaron en los comentarios tienes mal anidado `message.channel.send("mira atras tuyo :)");`, así es como debiese estar:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const  client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("CH0");
});
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("hola")) {
        message.channel.send("Hola que tal!");
    }
    if (message.content.startsWith("r!estoy solito")) {
        message.channel.send("mira atras tuyo :)");
    }
});
```

PD: trata de ser mas ordenado en cuanto a las aperturas y cierres de tus funciones, saludos!

Comment: Ok muchas gracias!, a la otra tratare de ser mas ordenado xd

Answer (score 0):

Al inicio de la función has de hacer que el bot no mire sus propios mensajes, te lo pongo abajo todo:

```
// copio todo aquí abajo *****************************

const Discord = require("discord.js");
const  client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("ready", () => {
   console.log("CH0");
});

client.on("message", (message) => {

  if (message.author.bot)  //NUEVO, si el author del mensaje es el bot, retornamos.
   return;

  if (message.content.startsWith("hola")) 
    message.channel.send("Hola que tal!");
  else
    if (message.content.startsWith("r!estoy solito")) 
      message.channel.send("mira atras tuyo :)");
});
```

Comment: por favor trata de explicar un poco el código (se que es fácil de entender, pero la explicación se agradece) :)